# Domain event dispatching using Entity<TId> on DbContext.SaveChanges

Tags: c#, entity-framework, domain-driven-design

I've implemented domain dispatching using a similar pattern [here](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/05/13/a-better-domain-events-pattern/) by overriding the `SaveChanges` method on my `DbContext`. I have entities with domain events that inherit a base abstract class that contains a list of domain events. I now want to enforce that the abstract class to have an Id property of a generic type.

Below is the base entity class before and after:

```
//BEFORE
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    public List<BaseDomainEvent> Events = new List<BaseDomainEvent>();
}

//AFTER
public abstract class BaseEntity<TId>
{
    public virtual TId Id { get; protected set; }

    public List<BaseDomainEvent> Events = new List<BaseDomainEvent>();

    protected BaseEntity(TId id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }

    // EF requires an empty constructor
    protected BaseEntity()
    {
    }
}
```

On my `DbContext.SaveChanges()` I'm having a problem finding entities that have events now that I've changed the `BaseEntity` class. Below you will find the code before and after.

```
//BEFORE
public override int SaveChanges()
{
        int result = base.SaveChanges();

        // dispatch events only if save was successful
        var entitiesWithEvents = ChangeTracker.Entries<BaseEntity>()
            .Select(e => e.Entity)
            .Where(e => e.Events.Any())
            .ToArray();

        foreach (var entity in entitiesWithEvents)
        {
            var events = entity.Events.ToArray();
            entity.Events.Clear();
            foreach (var domainEvent in events)
            {
                _dispatcher.Dispatch(domainEvent);
            }
        }

        return result;
}

//AFTER
public override int SaveChanges()
{
        int result = base.SaveChanges();

        // dispatch events only if save was successful
        var entitiesWithEvents = ChangeTracker.Entries<BaseEntity<object>>()
            .Select(e => e.Entity)
            .Where(e => e.Events.Any())
            .ToArray();

        foreach (var entity in entitiesWithEvents)
        {
            var events = entity.Events.ToArray();
            entity.Events.Clear();
            foreach (var domainEvent in events)
            {
                _dispatcher.Dispatch(domainEvent);
            }
        }

        return result;
}
```

I can change `ChangeTracker.Entries<BaseEntity<object>>()` to `ChangeTracker.Entries<BaseEntity<int>>()` and it works for all entities with the Id of int but not for the ones that may contain a Guid or String as the Id type.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to keep the original class and inherit from that:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    public List<BaseDomainEvent> Events = new List<BaseDomainEvent>();
}

public abstract class BaseEntity<TId> : BaseEntity
{
    public virtual TId Id { get; protected set; }

    protected BaseEntity(TId id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }

    // EF requires an empty constructor
    protected BaseEntity()
    {
    }
}
```

Now you don't need to change the `SaveChanges` method.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you!